# Using sequence() with more than 7 parsers

Tags: jparsec

I am trying to build a parser combinator that uses `Parsers.sequence()` but with more than 7 parsers, 26 to be exact. Unfortunately the `Parsers.sequence()` method only takes up to 7 parsers. I read on another stack overflow question that using `Parsers.List()` would be necessary. However, that seems to be an issue. That method returns a `List<Object>`. I use this parser to parse through 26 parsers where only 10 of them return a valuable token that I will use in a constructor to initialise an object from a custom class. Having a list of object isn't very good because I would have to downcast all the items in the list in the correct type for my constructor.

What is the better way of doing this?